# c++ pointer cast overload

Tags: c++, casting, overloading, operator-keyword

The Basic question is does anyone know a method for this in c++? Class 2 is subclass of Class1 and it has to stay that way.

```
Class1* a;
Class2* b = (Class2*)a;

basically allowing you
Class1* a;
Class2* b = a;


// tried this but didn't seem to work
class Class1
{
    operator Class2*() { return (Class2*)this; }
}
```

I couldn't really find anything sorry if that's a retarded question / duplicate but didn't quite get my head around this. Would appreciate if someoen had similar stuff.

Edit: some extra Information
Class1 = baseclass e.g Player
Class2 = subclass e.g Weapon

Class1 holds a pointer to the Subclass which has same values like origin

Player has a Pointer to Weapon
basically what I want to do is

GetEntity returns a Pointer of Type Player (but the return value could also be Weapon)

Basically now what I want to do is automate the process of casting it like

```
Player* p = GetEntity(0);
Player* p2 = GetEntity(1);
Weapon wpn = (Weapon*)p2;

//so that you are able to do
Weapon wpn = p2;

// Also that Stuff like that would be possible
void Test(Weapon *wpn);

Player *player = GetEntity(1);
// Yes I know this works Test((Weapon*)player) but I am lazy and that's the goal
Test(player);
```

without casting it.

Comment: Public inheritance...

Comment: Even if I inhert Class2 of Class1 I still need to cast the pointer which I'm trying to automate.

Comment: No, you make `Class1` inherit from `Class2`... Decide which *is-a* relationship your are after.

Comment: I can't since Class2 needs to be a subclass of Class1. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: What you tried would allow to convert a plain object (aka *a) into a pointer: that's a weird conversion... we need to know more about the relation between the classes and why you don't use static_cast nor dynamic_cast

Comment: Why do you actually need this? Modern C++ code shouldn't be dealing with raw pointers too often.

Comment: Well it's old stuff and I was just curious if there was a way which would make this work as I thought it should be similar to general cast operator overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact thing you're trying to achieve cannot be done. The reason is that the line `Class2* b = a;` does not deal with the class type at all, both `a` and `b` are of built-in pointer type. And there's no way to introduce custom behaviour of operations when all the operands are built-in non-enumeration types.

Comment: edited the post and gave some more information on what exactly is going on. the general casting does work but it produces a compiler error without the cast and that is exactly what I'm trying to fix in any way.

Comment: @NOBANPLZGod Your edit is nonsense. If `Weapon` is a type, you cannot do `Weapon = p2`, as that's trying to assign a value to a type. And anyway, the point stands: you cannot introduce conversion operators between two pointer types, period.

Comment: Yes I added it forgot to declare a variable name twice which made it look intentional which it wasn't.

Also in a string class casting it to return a char* works as well so where should be the difference in defining a custom Class pointer cast.  Still it sounds like you got a point so I'll try to find some more information on that topic.

Comment: @NOBANPLZGod When defining a custom conversion from `X` to `Y`, either `X` or `Y` (or both) must be a class or enumeration. That's the language's rules. In your case, they're both pointers: no can do.

Comment: hmm sounds logical I'll mark it as the answer I guess. Was just trying to get fix something annoying but I guess I learned something new cheers.